# SQL: Compare if column values in two tables are equal

Tags: mysql, join, compare, equals

I'm working on mysql and have two tables with the same schema:

**preTrial**

```
|id|accusedId|articleid|
------------------------
|1 |     1   |     1   |
|2 |     1   |     2   |
|3 |     1   |     3   |
|4 |     2   |     1   |
|5 |     2   |     2   |
```

**trial**

```
|id|accusedId|articleid|
------------------------
|1 |     1   |     1   |
|2 |     1   |     2   |
|3 |     2   |     1   |
|4 |     2   |     2   |
```

I want to get those `accusedIds` where all the `articleIds` of the first and the second tables are equal.

The above example should only return the accusedId 2, cause for accusedId 1 there is no articleId 3 in the second table.

I hope you understand what i mean. I'm currently writing my thesis in law, and the the time i was into sql is long gone by. Of course i already did some research, and tried several joins, but i was not able to find a solution. Hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select a.accusedId , sum(a.accusedid) as cnt_a, sum(coalesce(b.accusedId, 0)) as cnt_b
from a left join b on a.accusedId =  b.accusedId and a.articleId = b.articleId
group by accusedId
having cnt_a = cnt_b
```

I haven't even run that, so it might be a little off, but give it a lash. What it's doing is returning zeroes for a row in a not matched by b, so the HAVING clause will filter your grouped results to those where the article counts are equal.

Comment: thanks you for the solution and the explanation. just two notes: instead of `select accusedId` it should be `select a.accusedId`and no whitespace after sum, otherwise mysql throws an error. 
otherwise it works fine. you made my day

Comment: Edited answer to include suggestions. I'd like to second Gordon's sentiments; It wouldn't take more than a few seconds to accept the answer if it works. Cheers.

Comment: sorry i'm new to stackoverflow, and i thougt vote up an answer and accept it, is the same and i wasn't able to vote up due to low reputation. now, i accepted the answer.